# Marvolo Gaunt's Wife

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, slytherin

In the Harry Potter books, we never get to know who Voldemort's grandmother is on the Gaunt side; and in the memory in the 6th book, we only see Marvolo, Merope, and Morfin Gaunt. Does anyone know anything about Marvolo's wife and why we never saw her?

Comment: I've a feeling that she was Marvolo's cousin.

Comment: @Morrigan, interesting idea. It could be possible, because often when you look at pure-blood fanatics (like the Blacks), they often marry cousins.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dumbledore himself says in Half-Blood Prince that Gaunts had a tradition of marrying in their own family.

> "Voldemort's grandfather, yes," said Dumbledore. "Marvolo, his son,
> Morfin, and his daughter, Merope, were the last of the Gaunts, a very
> ancient Wizarding family noted for a vein of instability and violence
> that flourished through the generations due to their habit of marrying
> their own cousins.
>
> *~Half-Blood Prince, Ch 10: The hour of Gaunt*

On the website of Harry Potter Wiki (in the section of Marvolo Gaunt) his wife's name is not mentioned even in the Gaunt family tree.

> It was never mentioned about Marvolo's wife or how she was absent from
> the Gaunt shack (arguably most likely dying sometime before the arrest
> of her husband and son), but it could be surmised that given his
> terrible treatment of Merope, Marvolo also made for a horrible
> husband.
> (Link: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Marvolo_Gaunt)

Another link verifies the claim of Gaunts marrying into their family:

> The Gaunts are an ancient, **in-bred**, Pure-blood Wizarding family,
> direct descendants of Salazar Slytherin.
>
> (Link: https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/gaunt-family/)

So I guess its safe to assume that she was most definitely a family member, a cousin most likely.

Comment: The second quote would seem to be a case of wiki-based guesswork or self-invention. The first one, however, is a goodun and says all we really know about Voldemort's maternal gran.

Comment: [May be he was also his own grandfather](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/willienelson/immyowngrandpa.html)